# How can I get the type of a function that provides a const overload?

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class C
{
public:
    void f( int ) {}
    void f( int ) const {}
};
```

The only difference between the two overloads of `f` is that one of them is `const`. I can't use `decltype( &C::f )` because there is still ambiguity.

I want to get the function information by using a traits class, so I need to provide the function type.

Comment: You can't. The huge disadvantage of address of syntax for member functions is that they are context-dependent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force the non-`const` `C::f` overload to be chosen by passing `&C::f` to a function that expects a pointer to a non-`const` member function. To wit,

```
template <class C, class Ret, class... Args>
// trailing return type can be omitted in C++14
constexpr auto g(Ret (C::*p)(Args...)) -> decltype(p) {
    return p;
}

static_assert(std::is_same<void (C::*)(int), decltype(g(&C::f))>::value, "wrong overload");
```

(Note that additional work needs to be done if you want to support: C-style variadic functions, `volatile`-qualified functions, or ref-qualified functions.)

Comment: Heh, was just writing up an answer that did the opposite (`g` took a `const` pmf...) Guess I don't need to anymore, +1

Comment: In C++17, `noexcept` too. And with TM, `transaction_safe`. Enjoy the combinatorial explosion :)